# Ошибка при попытке вывести коллекцию объектов переданную через ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
var BalliStudnets = from balli in contextDB.tableBalli.ToList()
where balli.ID_Gruppi == Grupp_ID && balli.ID_Disciplini == Disciplina_ID
join s in contextDB.tableStudents on balli.ID_Studenta equals s.ID
select new
{
    Name = s.Name,
    Pos1 = balli.Pos1,
    Tek1 = balli.Tek1,
    Rub1 = balli.Rub1,
    Pos2 = balli.Pos2,
    Tek2 = balli.Tek2,
    Rub2 = balli.Rub2,
    Samost = balli.Samost,
    Dosdacha = balli.Dosdacha,Premial=balli.Premial,Itog=balli.Itog
};
ViewBag.Vedomost = BalliStudnets;
```

При передаче объекта `BalliStudnets` через `ViewBag` в представление, там компилятор ругается на то, что нет свойства `Name`. Он не видит свойства. Есть ли в запросе ошибка? Если, то что это может быть?

```
@foreach (var b in ViewBag.Vedomost)
{

    <tr>
        <td>@i</td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding:3px;">
            @b.Name
        </td>
        <td>@b.Pos1</td>
        <td>@b.Tek1</td>
        <td>@b.Rub1</td>
        <td>@b.Pos2</td>
        <td>@b.Tek2</td>
        <td>@b.Rub2</td>
        <td>@b.Samost</td>
        <td>@b.Dosdacha</td>
        <td>@b.Itog</td>
        <td>@b.Premial</td>

        @{i++;}
    </tr>

}
```

[image: Сама ошибка]

Comment: как используется этот объект во view?

Comment: Как массив для foreach.

Comment: добавь это использование в вопрос

Comment: попробуй заменить _var b_ на _dynamic b_

Comment: Сделал. Все равно тоже самое.

Comment: тогда, добавь в вопрос еще полный текст ошибки

Comment: Если не использовать метод join и возвращать просто select. Все работает. Ошибка появляется после использования join.
Сейчас добавлю текст ошибки.

Comment: хм, использование _dynamic_ должно было решить проблему

Comment: Там стоит dynamic. После того, как вы сказали я и не убирал.

Comment: @Grundy что то мне подсказывает что поможет приведение к конкретному типу.

Comment: а почему Вы не сделаете *строго типизированное представление*? и проблема тут на самом деле не в `linq`

Comment: @Bald, это само собой, но к анонимному типу не просто приводить :-)

Comment: да создайте модель Vedomost делов то

Comment: Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Нельзя обойтись без создания метода?

Comment: @Grundy dynamic не работает потому что анонимный класс имеет внутреннюю видимость

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а разве run-time binding не должен был сработать?

Comment: @Grundy нет. Это было бы нарушением безопасности.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте класс с описанием всех свойств вашей модели в папке Models

```
public class Vedomost{

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Pos1 { get; set; }
    public string Tek1 { get; set; }
    public string Rub1 { get; set; }
    public string Pos2 { get; set; }
    //etc...
}
```

Получаете результаты:

```
var BalliStudnets = from balli in contextDB.tableBalli.ToList()
                    where balli.ID_Gruppi == Grupp_ID && balli.ID_Disciplini == Disciplina_ID
                    join s in contextDB.tableStudents on balli.ID_Studenta equals s.ID
                    select new Vedomost // уже не анонимный класс
                    {
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Pos1 = balli.Pos1,
                        Tek1 = balli.Tek1,
                        Rub1 = balli.Rub1,
                        Pos2 = balli.Pos2,
                        Tek2 = balli.Tek2,
                        Rub2 = balli.Rub2,
                        Samost = balli.Samost,
                        Dosdacha = balli.Dosdacha,Premial=balli.Premial,Itog=balli.Itog
                    };
```

В представлении у вас будет доступ к свойствам вашей модели

```
@foreach (Vedomost  b in ViewBag.Vedomost)
{
//etc...
```

Анонимные типы являются типами класса, произведенными от объекта напрямую, и не могут быть приведены ни к какому иному типу, кроме объекта.Компилятор назначает имя для каждого анонимного типа, несмотря на то что для вашего приложения он недоступен. С точки зрения среды CLR анонимный тип не отличается от остальных ссылочных типов.

почитать тут [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Сделал. Все получилось. Спасибо!

Comment: А можете пояснить почему он ругался?

Comment: Результат который получался после select new был анонимным типов, который не имеет структуры. Компилятор не могу видеть его свойств. Создав класс Vedomost мы создали структуру данных для доступа к ним.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Результат который получался после select new был анонимным типом, который конечно же ИМЕЕТ структуру(для компилятора это обычный класс имя которому присвоит сам компилятор), но она нигде не была определена и поэтому когда нам нужно приести к какому-то конкретному типу - мы в тупике.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, пометьте его как "верный" (звёздочка внизу под рейтингом ответа), это поможет остальным пользователям ресурса понять решение. Спасибо.

Comment: @ЭркинМухамедкулов, звездочка - это добавить в избранное, а отметить принятым - это галочка

Comment: @Grundy Прошу прощения, был неправ. Спасибо.